# Is there a way to execute command from array with "for do"?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, lua

New to lua.

On example i have multiple

```lua
local part1 = display.newImage("part1.png", 0, 0)
part1:scale ( 0.5, 0.5)
part1.isVisible = false
...
local part10 = display.newImage("part10.png", 0, 0)
part10:scale ( 0.5, 0.5)
part10.isVisible = false
```

How can i optimize it using array and for do?

Like execute multiple commands from one for-loop whem command only has different numbers?

Im sure that this wont work but there should be a way to do what i want?

```lua
for i = 1, 10 do
  part[i]:scale ( 0.5, 0.5)
  part[i].isVisible = false
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
for i=1,10 do
  local part = display.newImage("part" .. i .. ".png", 0, 0)
  part:scale ( 0.5, 0.5)
  part.isVisible = false
end
```

Comment: I think OP probably wants something like `local parts = {} ... part[i] = `; From their example

Answer (score 0):

For this, you want to first define a table that will store all of your parts. Then, you create a loop that runs for however many parts you want (in your code, it's 10), and create each part in that loop. Here is an example:

```lua
local parts = {}
for i = 1, 10 do
    local part = display.newImage("part" .. tostring(i) .. ".png", 0, 0)
    part:scale(0.5, 0.5)
    part.isVisible = false
    table.insert(parts, part)
end
```

After this, you'll have a table full of parts, and can access them like so:

```
parts[part_num]
```

Hope this helps!